# InstallR failing in Mathematica 12

Tags: rlink

I was trying to use R with Mathematica 12

I tried the following:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.1", "Rversion" ->"3.5"]
```

I am getting this error

> JLink'Java: A Java exception occurred: com.wolfram.jlink.InvalidClassException: Invalid class specification. This class is not loaded into the current Java runtime. It might have been loaded into a different Java runtime, or Java might have been restarted since the class was loaded.

I have java version 8 update 211 installed on my machine.

Do I need a higher version of Java for this above command to work in Mathematica 12?

Please help how I can resolve this issue. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your platform? Windows 10?

Comment: Yes I have windows 10

Comment: The bug for this has been filed. I will try to look into this as soon as I get back from vacation, which is early August. In the mean time, can you consider working with earlier versions of R? IIRC, version 3.5.0 should work.

Comment: I don't have previous version of R, but I will check if I can get it, Thanks Leonid

Comment: The real issue currently is that while the bug has been reported by 2 independent users, I can't reproduce it locally yet, and neither can our QA folks (on our systems, everything seems to work fine). But we will surely look into this more.